# Thymeleaf with ajax, how to pass parameters

Tags: ajax, thymeleaf

In my html file: organigramme.html I have:

```
...
$(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : ${url},
                        dataType : "JSON",
                        success : function(result) {
                        alert(result);                              
                        },
                        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                    });
...
```

In my controller I have,

```
@GetMapping("/organigramme")
    public String organigramme(@RequestParam(name="id") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("url", "/getOrganigramme?id="+id);
        return "pages/organigramme";
    }
```

the ${url} value isn't replaced.

Is there a way to get the url value from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using inline JavaScript methodology to achieve that. Code sample is as follows:

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">

          /*<![CDATA[*/
            ...
            $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : /*[[${url}]]*/,
                        dataType : "JSON",
                        success : function(result) {
                        alert(result);                              
                        },
                        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                    });
...

           /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Please note the `th:inline="javascript"` property and also the `/*<![CDATA[*/` and `/*]]>*/` markings.